# Magento 1.9: Why aren't certain values showing on the Sales > Orders grid?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Why are the payment methods not showing on my Sales > Orders grid?

I can get the column showing with the drop down list of payment options but the payment method values are not showing on the list of orders.

This is the query that produces the orders list:

```
SELECT `main_table`.*, `payment`.`method` 
FROM 
`sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
INNER JOIN `sales_flat_order_payment` AS `payment`
ON main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id
```

The column I need to display the values for is called `method` and returns the correct results, for example `worldpay_cc`.  The values are returned from the query but just aren't showing in the grid.

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $collection->join(array('payment'=>'sales/order_payment'),'main_table.entity_id=payment.parent_id','method');
    $collection->addProductData();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}



protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('method', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Payment Method'),
        'index' => 'method',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => array(
            'worldpay_cc' => 'Worldpay',
            'cashondelivery' => 'Cash on Delivery',
            'pay' => 'Pay',
            'paypal_express' => 'Paypal Express',
        )          
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is $collection->addProductData()?

Comment: I wish I knew, I didn't write it ..... I'm just having to add a column into the grid and work with the existing code :(

Comment: I've just tried out your code, and it works fine for me. I found a place that had the addProductData code and added it to Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Grid_Collection and it seems to be working fine for me on the backend:

[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/MnePnOO.png)

Comment: @HarryMustoe-Playfair I don't know how to explain this but my original code appears to be working correctly as you mentioned.  I had flushed the cache  regularly to be sure it wasn't a caching issue.  Your code is an improvement though so I'll accept it.  Thank you for your help

Comment: have you checked compilation is turned off / recompiled? P.s. backend isn't cached as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah I checked that, compilation is off.  Most odd.  Thank you for helping me out though, much appreciated.

Comment: Weird - it just worked fine for me first time. My guess would be a third party extension conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that you haven't mapped the payment methods correctly maybe:

```
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('method', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Payment Method'),
        'index' => 'method',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => array(   // <--- The mapping, here
            'worldpay_cc' => 'Worldpay',
            'cashondelivery' => 'Cash on Delivery',
            'pay' => 'Pay',
            'paypal_express' => 'Paypal Express',
        )          
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

I would change the above to:

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('method', array(
        'header' => $this->__('Payment Method'),
        'index' => 'method',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => $this->getActivePaymentMethods()
    ));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}

public function getActivePaymentMethods()
{
    $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();
    $methods = array();
    foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
        $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
        $methods[$paymentCode] = $paymentTitle;
    }
    return $methods;
}
```

With reference to my comment, `addProductData` is a custom function:

```
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Grid_Collection

public function addProductData($attributesCodes)
{
    foreach ($attributesCodes as $attributeCode) {
        $attributeTableAlias = $attributeCode . '_table';
        $attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);

        $this->getSelect()->join(
           array($attributeTableAlias => $attribute->getBackendTable()),
             "main_table.product_id = {$attributeTableAlias}.entity_id AND {$attributeTableAlias}.attribute_id={$attribute->getId()}",
        array($attributeCode => 'value')
    );
        $this->_map['fields'][$attributeCode] = 'value';
    }
    return $this;
}
```